# How do i sort a 2d array by a particular element, in Perl?

Tags: arrays, sorting, perl, 2d

I have built a 2D array of scores and want to sort by the xth element (ie. the total).  The first element identifies the player: Array looks like this;

```
$array[0][0] = "name one";
$array[0][1] = n1; # (some number)
$array[0][2] = n2; # (some number)
$array[0][3] = n3; # (some number)
$array[0][4] = n4; # (Total of above 3)

$array[1][0] = "name two";
$array[1][1] = n1; # (some number)
$array[1][2] = n2; # (some number)
$array[1][3] = n3; # (some number)
$array[1][4] = n4; # (Total of above 3)
```

how do i sort by the 4th element of each dimension?
i tried

```
@new_array = sort { $a->[4] <=> $b->[4] || $a->[4] <=> $b->[4] } @array;
```

but got the original array back.

Comment: Your original array is 2 elements. It can only be "sorted" in 2 ways. What is this 4th element of which you speak? Is that `n4`? What is `n4`, is it a bareword? A sub? A string? What is it you hope to accomplish by comparing `n4 <=> n4`. (It does nothing).

Comment: To be clear: Getting the original array back is 50% of the random outcome. You either get the original, or you get it backwards, since you only have 2 elements. `1,2` or `2,1`.

Comment: (1) No need for the second `||` criterion ... it's the same as the first one?  Drop it. (2) You're sorting in increasing order, so you get first the array with the _smallest_ n4, etc. Perhaps that's your original order so it appears that nothing happened? Change to `sort { $b->[4] <=> $a->[4] }`.  Then it should work.

Comment: @zdim That wont work, because `n4 <=> n4` is 0 for all possible things that bareword `n4` can be. The OP needs to give more info, the question is unsolvable as is.

Comment: @TLP  I take it that those `n`s stand for (different) numbers that happen to be in arrayref's slots. So in the first arrayref (`$array[0]`) we'd have, say, `name1 2 4 4 10` (last is total), while in the second one it may be `name2 5 0 11 16` (so `$b->[4] <=> $a->[4]` is `16 <=> 10` etc). And I presume that it need be sorted so that the second array comes first.

Comment: @zdim Well, if that was the case, wouldn't the array be sorted correctly? Your theory sort of fits, but then again, what kind of madman would try the code with one set of data, and then replace the data with some weird placeholders to ask a question? Especially with a set of 2 data to sort, when really you have 50% chance to get it right just by random order. Something is wrong here.

Comment: @TLP "_wouldn't the array be sorted correctly_"  --- yes, and as I say in my comment I'm guessing that what confused them is that it is sorted in increasing sense (smallest first), which may be how their input comes, so they felt it wasn't working

Comment: @TLP Yeah, the question could clarify. I take it that these two either stand as a minimal example for more, or perhaps they dynamically get indeed only two data sets and need to process them larger-first; and, that they wanted to offer a generic format for a sample, with those `n`s etc.  Anyway, I hope that in my answer (which I contemplated of whether to post) I have a reasonable assumption of what the question means

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To sort arrayrefs in the array in decreasing order of their 5-th element

```
my @sorted_by_largest_total = sort { $b->[4] <=> $a->[4] } @data;
```

Or, if that "total" (the 5-th element) is indeed always the last element, better use index `-1` for the last element.  Then it doesn't matter if the number of players changes around, it still works.

```
my @sorted_by_largest_total = sort { $b->[-1] <=> $a->[-1] } @data;
```

I take it that the data is such that each arrayref has elements: name, then numbers (three as it stands in question's example), then total of those numbers.

Note that it is simpler with a very useful [Sort::Key](https://metacpan.org/pod/Sort::Key) module

```
use Sort::Key qw(rnkeysort);  # Reverse-Numerical

my @sorted_by_largest_total = rnkeysort { $_->[-1] } @data;
```

The library has a large number of functions for all kinds of generic criteria (like reverse-numerical here), and the more complicated the sorting the more it simplifies the job.

For example, if the scores to sort are strictly integer then there are `ikeysort` and `rikeysort`, and for unsigned integers -- likely for scores? -- there are `ukeysort` and `rukeysort`.

Comment: Thank you all for answering.  First off, my example showed only 2 players - there are actually 16 in the array, so sorting isn't a 50/50 chance.  And the problem turned out to be my example.  I shortened it so the total (and last element was the 4th - it actually had 8 elements to the 2nd dimension) - and there weren't any values in the 4th element yet.  But my sort formula used $a->[4] <=> $b->[4] because i copied it from my question - when i changed it to $a->[8] <=> $b->[8] - it sorted the array correctly.

Comment: @cjp Alright, thanks for clarifications.  I thought that it was probably more than 2, as I said in a comment below the question.  (And I corrected the "8" in the title, which clearly indicated that there was more stuff there. :)  And,  even if it were just two it would make perfect sense to sort -- if you need largest-first you have to, um, sort it, be it 2 or 200. Finally, as for 4 or 8 or x -- that's why I suggest in my answer that you use index `-1` -- the last element.  Then if your 8 later becomes 20 it still works.